# Debian on Synology NAS keeps changing timezone

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, time, synology

I have a Debian setup running on Synology NAS Virtual Machine Manager and it keeps changing the timezone.

[image: Debian VM]

At the top of the screenshot above you can see that the timezone was GMT -4.  then, at the bottom a few days later I check and the timezone is wrong (GMT -3).

Timezone is correct in Synology which is running the VM.

[image: Synology]

Is there something in Debian that might automatically change the timezone that I haven't checked?  Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I would suggest using same timezone on synology and debian.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just the offset, the first two time zones are different:

1. `America/Tortola`
2. `America/Bermuda`

and then the screen capture that you consider right shows:

3. `America/Manaus`.

Try to adjust not just the GMT offset, but the actual time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so this has happened a few times and each time I'm using timedatectl to change the time-zone info to America/Tortola.

Was just showing the offset amount to make the point.

Manaus is the time zone that I chose in Synology since it does not have a Tortola option.  Used to be La Paz which has the same timezone that I need but we thought maybe it was an undocumented glitch in the Syno VM package..  Did not change anything.

There must be some auto changing feature though..